# Outlook - Smart search

Tags: email, ms-office, search

Say I want to quickly find all emails by one person.

In some email editors you can type `"from: John"` and it would understand that you are only interested in messages that John **sent**.

Is this possible with Outlook in OS X? What about Mail?

Answer (score 4):

Outlook 2011 for Mac can do that: just skip the space. So, `from:John`.

It shows your smart search options as you type. Click one of these (or just type them with the colon), and it'll search only that type of thing:

[image]

---

Or, you can click in the quick search box, then click the **"From" button** in the "**search**" ribbon section that appears...

[image]

...then type "John" in the different box that appears.

Less typing, but one extra click.